# What will happen if I delete the empty 'iMovie' folder under my Documents folder

Tags: macos, imovie

I have an empty folder named iMovie stored in my Documents directory, `~/Documents/iMovies`.

I don't have any files in this folder but I notice it has a unique folder icon compared to other folders.

Can I delete it? Will there be any risk?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iMovie folder in Documents directory is the sync location for iMovie project files stored on iCloud.

> Can I delete it?

If you do not have any iMovie projects, it will be safe to delete.

> Will there be any risk?

No. The folder will be created anew by iMovie app when attempting to save project on iCloud.

The iMovie app is available and can be used on macOS, iOS or iPadOS